# Does the Color Ramp Node Normalize Values?

Tags: color

Often while working in the compositor, values are clamped between 0 and 1. Suppose I multiply a 0 to 1 image by 2 and put it through the Color Ramp node. Does it normalize the input such that the rightmost flag is controlling the values with a luminosity of 2? If so, is the output clamped between 0 and 1, or does it maintain the same range?